# Prevent merging certain local changes to files in version control in git

Tags: git, version-control

I'm wondering what is a good way of preventing certain local changes to be merged to a branch in git.

Concretely, I often find myself wanting to make local changes to source controlled files and have them applied while working on other changes but that I want to avoid being merged when I later merge with `master` or other branches.

Let's say I'm working on `feature-branch` and I make some of these changes. I don't want them just cluttering up my pending changes so I commit them as `hack-commit-1`. Then I do a bunch of other changes `A,B,...K` that I make as commit.

What are some good options to avoid committing the hack stuff to the main branch?

What I could do is rebasing onto a new branch before merging with main and ignore commits like `hack-commit-1` but this is rather manual and it's a bit too easy to forget or miss such a commit without proper discipline.

Another option I guess would be to work on a `private-feature-branch`, where I continuously `cherry-pick` commit to `feature-branch`.

What other options are there? Would be grateful on resources on the subject because I find it hard to find.

To be absolutely clear, I'm not asking about ignoring files but specific changes to files in version control.

## Edit:

I'm adding a [basic example repo](https://github.com/CervEdin/dont-commit-bad-stuff)

```
A-B <= origin master
   |\C-1-2-D-E-4 <= draft
   |C-D-E <= yes, master
   |1-2-4 <= no
```

What I usually end up with is something like `draft` and I find it to be a bit of a pain to separate that into `yes`/`no` branches after the fact. I can achieve this by rebasing but I wonder if there isn't a more efficient workflow less prone to error.

Comment: have you considered reverting the `hack-` commits before cleaning and pushing? if you are already squashing before pushing, `git revert` shouldn't introduce extra commits at origin, and I believe that the last active commit affecting those files would remain the commit prior to your original branching. wouldn't be too hard to script either. what do you think?

Comment: @FrankThomas, yes that's something I do but I find it a bit arduous to achieve after the fact

Comment: The answer most git pros would give is just don't stage changes you don't want committed. you can modify them all you like, and commit your other changes, without committing these, as long as you don;t stage them prior to commit. that said though, I understand the urge to use `git commit -am ...` so get where you are coming from, especially if you have to change branches when they want you to switch directions, and stashing code you don't want to commit ultimately is silly. so I'd give all your throwaway commits a name, write a script to query logs for ids of such commits, and revert them.

Comment: @FrankThomas mainly I want to commit them so they don't clutter the project directory and I don't have to take them into account when staging to the index. Also, they might be useful to me at some other point which is why it's nice to have them commited locally. I could try and achieve this through some kind of stash juggling, but when I do that the stashes tend to be become a mess

Comment: Welcome to this site. Does experimenting in new branches or stashing your changes locally do it?

Comment: @codezombie no not really :'D at least not in my current workflow. With stashing, I find it hard to separate discrete changes. I find stashing to easily become a bit of a mess with loads of stashes that are difficult to navigate, separate and apply. Branches work better but it becomes a real pain to switch between them when there are changes to project files; since I work in Visual Studio you get a really annoying prompt to reload whenever there's a modification to the project file.

Answer (score 0):

You may make `git pull --rebase` the default in these ways:

- Add this to your `.git/config` file:

  ```
    [branch "master"]
      rebase = true
  ```

  Or via the command line: `git config branch.master.rebase true`
- Add a global config option to always rebase when pulling:

  ```
    [branch]
      autosetuprebase = always
  ```

  Or via the command line: `git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always`
- Add an alias in `~/.gitconfig`

  ```
    [alias]
      pl = pull --rebase
  ```

  which will allow you to type `git pl`.

Comment: This is only seems to apply when tracking a remote branch, any way to apply the same when not?